# Customize CKEditor 3.0 with a downloaded template skin

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, fckeditor

How can I customize the skin for CKEditor 3.0? I downloaded a new skin and I have this JavaScript powering it at the moment:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'pageBody',
    {
        toolbar :
        [
            ['Format'],
            ['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', '-', 'About']
        ],
    });
```

I wanted to have a WordPress editor on my CMS, which is TinyMCE, but it's way complicated. So I turned to CKEditor and want to make it look better with a skin I downloaded.

Comment: What exactly do you want to customize??

Answer (score 6):

Underneath the closing `],` add:

```
skin : 'name_of_skin',
```

So it will end up like this:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'pageBody',
{
  toolbar :
  [
      ['Format'],
      ['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', '-', 'About']
  ],
  skin : 'name_of_skin',
});
```